# Is there a way to retrieve compute model of Azure SQL database in powershell script

Tags: powershell, azure-sql-database, azure-powershell

I'm trying to get a list of all "**Provisioned**" (not "Serverless") Azure databases from particular subscription using Powershell. I'm fairly new to ps, so probably I don't see something very obvious. In Set-AzSQLDatabase method there is a parameter -ComputeModel, however, I can not find corresponding parameter or property to filter on for use in Get-AzSQLDatabase. Can it be done in powershell script? Would really appreciate any pointers in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `ComputeModel` property in the result of `Get-AzSQLDatabase`, the option is to use [`Get-AzResource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azresource?view=azps-4.6.1).

There is a `Kind` property in the result of the command, for `Provisioned` database, it is `v12.0,user,vcore`, for `Serverless` database, it is `v12.0,user,vcore,serverless`, so we can use it to filter the databases in your subscription.

Sample:

```
Get-AzResource -ResourceType Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases | Where-Object {$_.Kind -eq 'v12.0,user,vcore'} | ft
```

[image]

If you want to get details about the databases, you could use `ConvertTo-Json`.

```
Get-AzResource -ResourceType Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases | Where-Object {$_.Kind -eq 'v12.0,user,vcore'} | ConvertTo-Json
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Joy Wang, this is very helpful, I'll definitely try that.