# How to set the ComputeModel property to Serverless on an Azure SQL Database using PowerShell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-sql-database

I'm restoring an Azure SQL Database (Serverless) from a deleted database backup using Get-AzSqlDeletedDatabaseBackup and Restore-AzSqlDatabase PowerShell commandlets.  The restore works, but the tags and ComputeModel are not restored with the database.

I've tried using Set-AzSqlDatabase:

```
Set-AzSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroupname -DatabaseName $databasename -ServerName $servername -ComputeModel "Serverless" -AutoPauseDelayInMinutes 45
```

Update: I tried the following code and the Kind is set prior to using the Set-AzResource cmdlet, but it doesn't stick

```
$resource = Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroupname -ResourceType "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases" -Name "$servername/$databasename"

Write-Host "Setting ComputeModel to Serverless..."
$resource.Kind = "v12.0,user,vcore,serverless"
$resource  
# resource.Kind is successfully set on the $resource object

Write-Host "Set-AzResource..."
$resource | Set-AzResource -Force
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Thank you.

Cheers,

Andy

Comment: What error are you seeing? According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/serverless-tier-overview?WT.mc_id=dataexposed-c9-niner&view=azuresql#use-powershell-1 the Set-AzSqlDatabase approach should be ok.

Comment: No error appears calling the Set-AzSqlDatabase cmdlet - the database is restored with the compute model set to "Provisioned"

Comment: Hi andyz - I had to test this since I couldn't sleep well with this not working. :-) I ran your Set-AzSqlDatabase and got the same result as you. No error but also no updated DB.  So, it seems that Set-AzSqlDatabase cmdlet needs -MinVcore and -MaxVcore parameters. And also, an autopausedelay of 45 minutes is not supported - it must be a minimum of 60 minutes. So when I ran `Set-AzSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName $rgName -DatabaseName $dbName -ServerName $srvName -ComputeModel Serverless -AutoPauseDelayInMinutes 60 -MinVcore 1 -MaxVcore 4` it worked for me.

Comment: @holger - Thank you!  Success!!!!  I'll throw my solution in and give you credit...unless you would like to post it?

Comment: That's great news! No need to give me credit, I just threw in an idea and didn't formulate a full solution. :-) I'd be interested in yours though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @holger and @Delliganesh Sevanesan for the help, I was able implement a solution that restores the most recent deleted database (SQL Database), adds some resource tags, and sets the ComputeModel to serverless.

Here's the code:

```
<# 
Purpose: Restore the most recently deleted Azure Sql Database

Dependencies:
    Az.Sql PowerShell module
#>

# Set variables first
$resourcegroupname = 'myresourcegroup'
$servername = 'myservername'
$databasename = 'mydatabasename'

[hashtable]$tags = @{ 
    application = "testing"
}

try {
    $deleteddatabases = Get-AzSqlDeletedDatabaseBackup -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroupname -ServerName $servername -DatabaseName $databasename
} catch {
    Write-Error "Error getting database backups [Get-AzSqlDeletedDatabaseBackup]: " + $_.Exception.Message
    exit(1)
}

# Get most recent backup in case there are multiple copies
# Assumes index and order in foreach is the same - proven in test
Write-Host "Database backups:"
$index = 0
$MostRecentBackupIndex = 0
$MostRecentBackupDate = (Get-date).AddDays(-2) # initialize variable with date from two days ago
foreach ($db in $deleteddatabases) {
    if ($db.CreationDate -ge $MostRecentBackupDate) {
        $MostRecentBackupIndex = $index
        $MostRecentBackupDate = $db.CreationDate
        Write-Host "Most Recent Database: $($db.DatabaseName) : Created: $($db.CreationDate) : DeleteDate: $($db.DeletionDate)"
    }
    $index++
}

$deleteddatabase = $deleteddatabases[$MostRecentBackupIndex]

Write-Host "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
Write-Host "Restoring: $($deleteddatabase.DatabaseName) from: $($deleteddatabase.CreationDate) backup"
Write-Host "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------"

Write-Host "Deleted database info ResourceId: "
Write-Host $deleteddatabase.ResourceId

try {
    Restore-AzSqlDatabase -FromDeletedDatabaseBackup `
        -DeletionDate $deleteddatabase.DeletionDate `
        -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroupname `
        -ServerName $servername `
        -TargetDatabaseName $databasename `
        -ResourceId $deleteddatabase.ResourceID `
        -Edition $deleteddatabase.Edition `
        -Vcore 2 `
        -ComputeGeneration "Gen5" 
} catch {
    Write-Error "Error restoring database [Restore-AzSqlDatabase]: " + $_.Exception.Message
    exit(1)
}

# Wait a few minutes to allow restore to complete before applying the tags
Start-Sleep -Seconds 180

Write-Host "Applying tags to database..."
try {
    $resource = Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroupname -ResourceType "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases" -Name "$servername/$databasename"
    New-AzTag -ResourceId $resource.Id -Tag $tags
} catch {
    Write-Error "Error adding tags to database [Get-AzResource, New-AzTag]: " + $_.Exception.Message
    exit(1)
}

Write-Host "Setting ComputeModel to Serverless..."
try {
    # Important - must include -AutoPauseDelayInMinutes 60, -MinVcore, and MaxVcore parameters (thanks holger)
    Set-AzSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroupname -DatabaseName $databasename -ServerName $servername -ComputeModel Serverless -AutoPauseDelayInMinutes 60 -MinVcore 1 -MaxVcore 2
} catch {
    Write-Error "Error setting serverless mode [Set-AzSqlDatabase]: " + $_.Exception.Message
    exit(1)
}

Write-Host "Database restore complete."
```

Answer (score 0):

The **[Get-AzSqlDeletedDatabaseBackup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/get-azsqldeleteddatabasebackup?view=azps-8.3.0)** and **[Restore-AzSqlDatabase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/restore-azsqldatabase?view=azps-8.3.0)** PowerShell cmdlets are doesn't contain a property to get the **ComputeModel**.

While **Restore** and **Delete Backup** database we don't require the **ComputeModel** properties. while setting database we need to require the **ComputeModel**.

If you want to get the compute model for the Azure SQL Database you can use, **Get-AzResource** command to fetch the specific information.

Thanks @joy wang [SO Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63822021/15997690) we can get the serverless Azure SQL Database.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Delliganesh - that can be helpful for "retrieving" the ComputeModel and gives me an idea - I'm going to try using the Set-AzResource cmdlet.

Comment: Tried using the Set-AzResource cmdlet, but the change does not get pushed to Azure.
I also tried this:
`Set-AzSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroupname -ServerName $servername -DatabaseName $databasename -ComputeModel "Serverless"
`
but no joy.

Comment: The `Set-AzSqlDatabase` cmdlet is used to **Set(update)** properties in a Azure SQL Database.  Make sure before using `Set-AzSqlDatabase` you have to create Azure SQL database using `New-AzSqlDatabase`.

Comment: I'm using `Restore-AzSqlDatabase -FromDeletedDatabaseBackup...` to restore the database vs creating it from scratch.  The database exists, as I'm able to add tags using the `New-AzTag` cmdlet.  
Using `Set-AzSqlDatabase` does not throw any errors, but the ComputeModel is not updated